# How to make my code to find the largest group of anagrams throughout the entire list?

Tags: python, sorting, anagram

Hi I'm new to Python and I've written code to find the largest anagram group in a list of words that's sorted alphabetically.Problem is, it only checks if two words which are SIDE BY SIDE are anagrams so it doesn't check through the entire list.
For example, if the list is

```
['afd','daf','fad','htrw']
```

it will have the correct output :

```
['afd','daf','fad']
```

But if its separate like:

```
['afd','bcf','daf','fad']
```

Then the output will be:

```
['daf','fad']
```

which is wrong.

This is a section of my code?

```
index=1
#PROBLEM HERE??
while index<len(arr):
    if areAnagrams(firstWord,arr[index]):
       groupLength+=1
       if groupLength>largestGroupSize:
           largestGroupIndexStart=groupIndex
           largestGroupSize=groupLength
           largestGroupIndexEnd=index

    else:
        firstWord=arr[index]
        groupLength=1
        groupIndex=index
    index+=1
```

Any help will be appreciated thanks!

Comment: What's the expected output for `['afd','bcf','daf','fad']`?

Comment: It should be ['afd','daf','fad'] so it should iterate throughput the list but it only searches for anagrams which are side by side

Answer (score 3):

You can use an approach that is independent from the fact that your words are sorted alphabetically.

1./ first you group all the words that are anagrams of each other together so you have multiple lists
2./ then you pick the longest list

```
from collections import defaultdict

anagrams_list = ['afd','bcf','daf','fad']
anagrams_map = defaultdict(list)  # defaultdict creates a default type for each new dict attribute accessed: here list
for ana in anagrams_list:
    # each anagram has the same "signature": they are all made from the same letters
    # so we use this signature as the key
    # and associate to the key all the anarams versions we have
    anagrams_map[''.join(sorted(ana))].append(ana)
# Then we find the dict key which is associated with the longest list
max_key = max(anagrams_map, key= lambda x: len(set(anagrams_map[x])))
# We print it: it will already be alphabetically sorted as anagrams_list was sorted too
# if the initial list isn't sorted, you can sort the list here
print(anagrams_map[max_key])
```

***Note (see  Ilja Everilä comment):*** this is the general case anagrams where words are re-arrangement of each other letters `(scar VS cars)`.
if you also want to group words that are simply using ALL of the same letters `(hello VS hole)` you can use a frozen set for the unique key:

```
anagrams_map[frozenset(ana)].append(ana)
```

instead of

```
anagrams_map[''.join(sorted(ana))].append(ana)
```

Comment: The lookup keys could also be frozen sets.

Comment: @IljaEverilä You're right, I was thinking of using that too first, but I think the anagrams should handle character repetition, and `frozenset("hello")` -> `frozenset({'e', 'h', 'l', 'o'})`... I think it depends on how people define anagrams, I'm not so sure: e.g whether you consider `hello` and `hole` anagrams or not

Comment: Totally overlooked repetitions. You're absolutely right.